# Issue when using 'order' in a function in R

Tags: r

i recently started coding R and love it.

However, while experimenting with functions, i have encountered an issue.
I have problems when i try to use 'order' inside my function.

When i use my function below, i get:

> Error in order(dataset$column) : argument 1 is not a vector

I have tried searching for an anwer but with no luck. Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
#sample random data
testdata <- as.data.frame(rnorm(100, 10, 1))
colnames(testdata) <- "x"
testdata$y <- rnorm(100, 20, 3) 

#ABC function
ABC_anal <- function(dataset, column, c_limit = 0.10, b_limit = 0.20){

  data_order <- 1:length(dataset$column)
  dataset$vec_order <- data_order

  dataset <- dataset[order(dataset$column),]

  total <- sum(dataset$column)

  for (i in 1:length(dataset$column)) dataset$Accummulated[i] <- sum(dataset$column[1:i])

  dataset$percentage <- dataset$Acummulated / total * 100

  dataset$ABC <- ifelse(dataset$column < c_limit,"C", ifelse(dataset$column < b_limit,"B","A"))

  dataset <- dataset[order(dataset$vec_order),]

  return(dataset$ABC)
}

#applying
ABC_anal(dataset = testdata, column = y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataset` is an object. `column` is an object. `dataset$column` is not a valid object. You're not accessing columns inside your dataframe correctly.

See what happens when you try `testdata$column` outside your function:

```
testdata$column
NULL # ie it doesn't exist
```

You need to access your column correctly. Honestly, your function really shouldn't run at all because `y` is not a valid object in your environment so the function call shouldn't be able to evaluate it. It only runs because R executes lazily, so the parameter `column=y` isn't evaluated until it's needed. And at that point it fails.

There are several solutions, most of which involve changing the input parameter `column` to either a string or an integer eg:

```
ABC_anal <- function(dataset, column= "y"){...}
ABC_anal <- function(dataset, column= 2L){...}
```

From there any of:

```
get("y", envir= as.environment(testdata)) #character
testdata[, which(names(testdata) == column)] #character
testdata[, column] #integer
```